# Problem using C++ DLL functions in C# code

Tags: c#, c++, dll, import

```
[DllImport(pathimportdll)]
static extern int InitiateSession(ref _SESSION_INFO sinfo, ref _DEVICE_INFO pDevInfo);

[DllImport(pathimportdll)]
static extern int StartAcquisition();
```

DLL functions are imported properly. After the call, application is asserting in tcscpy.inl with the message Expression: (L"Buffer is too small" && 0).

Comment: Some more code would be helpfull. If DLL functions are imported properly why ould you get an assertion?

Comment: What makes you think it's a DLL problem? The assertion seems to come from memcpy or strcpy kind of function.

Comment: Without seeing the original declarations of the functions and the structures AND your C# declaration, its impossible to suggest a solution.

Comment: The error means string cannot be copied to some buffer, because the buffer is too small. Does one of the objects you pass into the DLL contain a buffer, which should receive a string? If so, that buffer is probably not large enough.

Answer (score 0):

*

> "DLL functions are imported properly"

*

that's most likely debatable. one way to be sure is to comment out your **dllimport** code and not invoke it.  if you **don't** get the error then one can most likely assume your import declarations are not quite correct.